# Is there a way to have static prototypes AND public ones in the same header file in C?

Tags: c, static, header

The compiler will always whine when I have mixed public with static prototypes in a header file.

Say I have header main.h with a static prototype for function *a* and a normal prototype for function *b*. Then I want to `#include` the header in two .c files, namely main.c and other.c. In main.c I need an include as I call the function before any prototype.

main.h:

```
static int a(void);
int b(void);
```

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
void main(){
  a();
}

static int a(void){
  /* do stuff */  
}

int b(void){  
  /* do stuff */  
}
```

other.c:

```
#include "main.h"
b();
```

What's the best practice for this than the obvious solution of splitting the header file into a seperate header exclusively for static prototypes and one for public ones?

Comment: Why do you need the prototype of a static function in a header anyway? Also, `void main()`? If you're not working on embedded systems you've got some explaining to do...

Comment: @Chris I know that it should be int. Just wanted to make the code as small as possible so I would get an answer :)

Comment: I appreciate the effort not to dump code, but no one will be put off by `return 0;` ;)

Comment: @Chris: Hopefully no-one would be put off by `int main()` without `return 0;` either, and that's the shortest of all. Even those afflicted with a primitive compiler should at least have *heard* of C99 ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't put declarations of static functions in header files. Since they are local to the `.c` file that defines them, it doesn't make sense to export them from a header file.

There are two things you can do:

1. Define the function before it is called in the c file (move definition of `a()` above main).
2. Declare static function at the top of the C file (this is my personal choice). In your case, you move the declaration of `a()` to the top of `main.c`.

If the function is going to be used in multiple translation units, then you can define the static function in the header file. It could usefully be inline instead of static assuming you have a grown-up compiler that supports C99.

Comment: 3. define the static function in the header file. In this example, `a` is used in only one TU, so probably it shouldn't be in the header at all (2 is right). But if you're actually going to use `a` in multiple TUs, it should be defined in the header, and could usefully be `inline` instead of `static` assuming you have a grown-up compiler that supports C99.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense having static prototypes in a header, the reason for this is that static functions have file scope so no module outside can anyway access the functions.

Instead I would suggest you put static prototypes only in the .c file at the top of the file in the same file they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the declaration of `b()` in `main.h`, why do you need it again in `other.c` that includes it? Other than that, it's all good, can't see any issue.

The important point to keep in mind about the "normal" functions is that all the forward declarations of the same function (`b()` in this case) must match, otherwise you'll have trouble (linking errors, compiler errors, what's not). In your case they don't match.

Unless of course `b();` is an actual call to the function, but at least in the code you posted its out of any scope, thus is treated as a forward declaration.

Re the `static` forward declarations, they limit the visibility of the function to the compilation unit. So calling `a()` in `other.c` **will not** execute the `a()` implemented in `main.c`. That's the whole point of `static` in C.

Answer (score 1):

IF the "static" function you want to define is short enough or cheap enough, you'll better define it as **static inline** and put its definition with its body (not only its declaration) in the **.h* header file.